# Binary Cross Entropy | Manual scalars

Tags: python, loss-function, data-science-model, binary

I am wanting to make print statements "showing my working out" of `Binary Cross Entropy` loss function, that works with `scalar` inputs, not arrays.

```
import math as m
import numpy as np

y_ans = 1
y_pred = 1

print("Cost(y,y^) = -yln(y^) - (1-y)-y^ln(1-y^)")
print('Cost('+str(y_ans)+', '+str(y_pred)+') = -'+str(y_ans)+'ln('+str(y_pred)+') -('+str(1-y_ans)+')ln('+str(1-y_pred)+')')
#ans = round((-y_ans*m.log(y_pred)) - ((1-y_ans)*m.log(1-y_pred)), 2)
ans = round((-y_ans*np.log(y_pred)) - ((1-y_ans)*np.log(1-y_pred)), 2)
print('Cost('+str(y_ans)+', '+str(y_pred)+') = '+str(ans))
```

The answer should be `0`, but I get `NaN`

```
Cost(y,y^) = -yln(y^) - (1-y)-y^ln(1-y^)
Cost(1, 1) = -1ln(1) -(0)ln(0)
/home/runner/MalwareAnalysis/BinaryCrossEntropy.py:10: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  ans = round((-y_ans*np.log(y_pred)) - ((1-y_ans)*np.log(1-y_pred)), 2)
/home/runner/MalwareAnalysis/BinaryCrossEntropy.py:10: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ans = round((-y_ans*np.log(y_pred)) - ((1-y_ans)*np.log(1-y_pred)), 2)
Cost(1, 1) = nan
```

```
print((-y_ans*np.log(y_pred)))
-0.0
print((1-y_ans)*np.log(1-y_pred))
nan
```

I'm fairly new to Python.

Comment: `np.log(1-y_pred)` will try to take the log of 0, which is not defined. Using a value for `y_pred` that is lower than 1 works perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm not sure as to what the solution is from what you are saying. I have appended outputs to the 2 halves to see if that helps anyone answer

Comment: The issue is that the second part of the cost function (`((1-y_ans)*np.log(1-y_pred))`) will return a nan value since `np.log(1-y_pred)` tries to take the log of zero, which is undefined. You can use something like `numpy.nan_to_num` to automatically convert any nan values to zero.

Comment: Tysm :) Working now

Answer (score 0):

`np.nan_to_num()` does the trick, as @Oxbowerce pointed out.

```
import numpy as np
np.nan_to_num(np.log(1-y_pred))
```